# How can I make same name variable with for()

Tags: objective-c

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        Monster *[NSString stringWithFormat:@"monster%d", i];
}
```

Like this, I want to make 'monster0, monster1, monster2, monster3, monster4' variable. But this behavior is error. Any other syntax is existed? Please tell me. Thanks.

Comment: Why you do not use array?

Comment: Its not possible. As suggested by @HuseinBehbudiRad go with an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You can not variably assign the pointer name. And there is no good reason for even doing so. When the loop iterates, you can create new monsters with the same pointer name, because it doesn't at all matter what you name the pointer, every one will be a reference to different Monster object.

If however, your monster needs to know what its "number" is, you could add a property to it to pass the value in.

Example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    Monster *monster = [[Monster alloc] init];
    monster.monsterNumber = i;
    [self.view addSubview:monster];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I make it with 'monster.name'